# P(X+Y<a | X<a) for X, Y normal and independent distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and let X and Y be independent normally distributed random variables, with mean $0$ and respective variances $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$. Can we express $$P(X+Y<a\,|\,X<a)$$ with a simple formula (say elementary functions + erf)?

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157605/caculate-the-probability-of-sum-of-normal-distribution?rq=1) more general one, which hasn't been answered.

Comment: Can you please clarify if the mean is the letter "o" or the number "0"?

Comment: Just a small remark on your terminology: I think you mean that X and Y are normally distributed *random variables*.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct.